# Convert an input file from lower case to upper case

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tr

I have a text file as "temp" with contents

```
Hai! How are you
```

I wanted to change the contents of the same file to

```
HAI! HOW ARE YOU
```

When i used 
`cat temp |tr a-z A-Z` (---only output was shown as upper case. The file remain unchanged....). I wanted the file contents to be changed.
On Using `cat temp |tr a-z A-Z>>temp` (--the out was appended not overwritten). Kindly help

Comment: Welcome to SO, please try to wrap your samples in CODE TAGS a `{}` button in your post, also try to show your efforts too(in code tags only).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary file to store the result:

```
cat temp | tr "a-z" "A-Z" > t
rm temp
mv t temp
```

Using `sed` should also work:

```
sed -i 's/./\U&/g' temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Read content from temp, convert it to upper case and write it back to temp:

```
echo "$(awk '{print toupper($0)}' < temp)" > temp
```

Comment: I believe same solution is given here too https://stackoverflow.com/a/51243990/5866580  :) cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
cat temp |tr a-z A-Z>>temp
```

will not overwrite becouse of double '>'

---

To overwrite content use single  '>'

```
cat temp |tr a-z A-Z>temp
```

Comment: Thanks Adam. Using the above only makes change to the first character in the file.

Comment: Could You explain -1 vote? I am right about how cat outstream is working